# Difference between cron plugin and Timer.periodic in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, background, scheduling

```
**every 5 seconds something will be called**

Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
  //something();

});

**every 1 minute something() will be called.**
  var cron = new Cron();
cron.schedule(new Schedule.parse('*/1 * * * *'), () async {
 // something();

});
```

**but both don't execute the job if is the app no longer in the memory.**

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of Cron over Timer is that with Cron Syntax you can specify complex time intervals and not only constant duration intervals.

For example it's difficult to execute a function every day at a specific time (e.g 6:05pm) with Timer because it depends on your start time to which it adds a constant duration, not like Cron you can just put:

```
var cron = new Cron();
cron.schedule(new Schedule.parse('5 6 * * *'), () async {
// something();
});
```

To sum up, if your goal is only to repeat a task over a constant interval use Timer, if you goal is more complex like repeating a task every 2 months in weekdays at 6pm you may need Cron.

```
var cron = new Cron();
cron.schedule(new Schedule.parse('0 6 * */2 MON-FRI'), () async {
// something();
});
```

Here is a link to know more about Cron syntax : [corn syntax](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm)

Comment: thanks for answering I appreciate that, but there is a way to schedule a job even if the app is no longer in the memory

Comment: Please upvote my first answer if it answers your first question.
For you second question : No, in Flutter it's not possible, but what you can do is to launch your callback function (the one you repeat periodically in cron) once at the start of your app to cover up all missed ticks.